# how to write a case statement like sql in pivotal gemfire query

Tags: gemfire

Sample sql query:

```
select name,  
lastname,  
city, 
case when city='Mumbai' then '01' else '02' end as Code 
from products
```

How to write above query in pivotal gemfire using case statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported when using native OQL, you need to implement the use case using another approach, like executing a function that filters the results directly on server side before returning the objects. More details about this can be found in [Function Execution](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html).

That said, there's already an improvement request created for this functionality, you can follow the progress by adding yourself as a watcher to [GEODE-4040](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-4040).

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: is this functionality available now? We are using gemfire 9 @juanramos

Comment: No, it's not available yet @KCK.